# kafka efficient way to ignore self produced messages

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

i just started learning kafka. I have an application whose multiple instances can run.

each instance has producer and consumer. each instance request data by sending message using producer API and other's are supposed to receive the message through consumer API.

now because there is only one topic on which data is being exchange and each instance is producer and consumer for the same topic, the same instance gets the self created message. this is kind of expected behavior.

My question:
What is the efficient way to ignore the self created messages on the given application instance?

I am using c++ librdkafka library on linux box.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can embed an application id (as producer application's id) into your messages that is checked upon delivery, and ignored if that id matches the receiving application's id.

Comment: Starting with the next release of librdkafka (end of february) you can also use Message Headers for this purpose: when producing messages add a header identifying the source application, and on consumption look up that same header and if the source matches the destination application.